# match data across rows for paired ratings

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with pairs of individuals who rated themselves (1,0) and rated their partner (1,0).

```
have <- data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                   person=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                   rateSelf=c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                   rateOther=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
have

#  group person rateSelf rateOther
#1     1      1        1         1
#2     1      2        0         1
#3     2      1        1         1
#4     2      2        0         0
#5     3      1        1         0
#6     3      2        0         0
```

I want to compare how someone rated themselves (`rateSelf`) to how they were rated by the other person (`ratedByOther`).

```
want <- data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                   person=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                   rateSelf=c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                   rateOther=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                   ratedByOther=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
want

#  group person rateSelf rateOther ratedByOther
#1     1      1        1         1            1
#2     1      2        0         1            1
#3     2      1        1         1            0
#4     2      2        0         0            1
#5     3      1        1         0            0
#6     3      2        0         0            0
```

What's a smart way to get `ratedByOther`?

Comment: It is not clear about the logic of getting `ratedByOther`

Comment: Let's say I'm `person` 1 in `group` 2, and you're `person` 2 in `group` 2. I rate myself (`have[3,3]==1`) and rate you (`have[3,4]==1`). I want to compare how I rated myself (1) to how you rated me (`have[4,4]==0`). I need to get your rating of me in my row.

Comment: `have$rateByOther <- with(have, ave(rateOther, group, FUN = rev))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this does what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
want <- have %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(ratedByOther = rev(rateOther))

  group person rateSelf rateOther ratedByOther
  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1      1        1         1            1
2     1      2        0         1            1
3     2      1        1         1            0
4     2      2        0         0            1
5     3      1        1         0            0
6     3      2        0         0            0
```

Comment: `rev()` to the rescue. nice!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(have)[, ratedByOther := rev(rateOther), group]
```